# Drupal - front end in/out of stock

Tags: drupal, inventory, stock, levels

My client has an e-commerce site made in Drupal. Exclusively for the stock levels shown in the front-end (product "in stock", "out of stock") a previous developer programed drupal to get this information from an external API.

Well, now I must turn this feature back to get stock levels from drupal's internal inventory management, but I just can't figure it out how to do that.

I know well php but nothing of drupal.

I saw there is a "ubercart" folder but I can't say if it's working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case You use **Ubercart** module to create Drupal e-commerce site.
Ubercart has Stock submodule. You can activate it on /admin/modules page.
After this action You'll have stock inventory in product content type